# How to let Yii2 respond with different HTTP response? Will be created in library.

Tags: yii2, httpresponse, tcpdf, fpdf

I'm using FPDF/TCPDF with Yii2. Both libraries (and others as well) can directly send data to the client. So the Yii2 response is not necessary. It even must be switched off. How can I do this?

Currently I get the following error which can be found at the end of the created PDF file (using a text editor):

> yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in /var/www/html/production-service/vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1017. in /var/www/html/my-app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:378

with the following code:

```
class MyController extends yii\web\Controller {
    public function actionCreatePdf() {
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        ...
        $pdf->Output('D', 'my.pdf');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have something writing to the output stream BEFORE $pdf->Output call, maybe in a BeforeAction or an echo.

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the whole Yii2 responding you can simply do this:

```
public function actionCreatePdf() {
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    ...
    $pdf->Output('D', 'my.pdf');
    Yii::$app->response->isSent = true; // <-------------
}
```

[`isSent`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#$isSent-detail) set to true will prevent that Yii2 sends anything (headers, cookies) to the client for the given action. Note that this will also suppress the [response events](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#events) - but not the others ([application events](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#events), [controller events](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#events)).

If the property gets set late (at end of action), preceding exceptions can be sent regularly to the client (content, headers, cookies are not suppressed).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Response::$isSent`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#$isSent-detail) property is not reliable. It works for as long as everything is OK. But if you get an exception during response generation (for example `FPDF` could throw an exception), you will get `HeadersAlreadySentException` again, since error handler resets response object and sends it again. The only bulletproof solution as I know is to create dump response object which does not send anything, and set in as `response` component:

```
class DumbResponse extends \yii\web\Response {

    public function send() {
    }
}
```

And in controller action:

```
public function actionCreatePdf() {
    Yii::$app->setComponents([
        'response' => DumbResponse::class
    ]);

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    // ...
    $pdf->Output('D', 'my.pdf');
}
```